# Fedora 27 to Fedora 28 upgrade gives following message

Tags: linux, fedora, upgrade, dnf

I am trying to upgrade my Fedora 27 (using dnf) to Fedora 28, but the last month I keep got that message error:

```
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=28
Before you continue ensure that your system is fully upgraded by running "dnf --refresh upgrade". Do you want to continue [y/N]: y
RPM Fusion for Fedora 28 - Nonfree - Updates    417 kB/s |  96 kB     00:00    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:00 ago on Sat 17 Nov 2018 09:12:47 AM EET.
Error: 
 Problem: nss-pem-1.0.3-6.fc27.i686 has inferior architecture
  - nss-pem-1.0.3-6.fc27.x86_64 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
  - problem with installed package nss-pem-1.0.3-6.fc27.i686
```

Does anybody know how to fix that? I was not able to find any info about that ticket and how to resolve it.

Comment: What is the output of `rpm -q --whatrequires nss-pem`?

Comment: Apparently this:
rpm -q --whatrequires nss-pem
no package requires nss-pem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that expressed that bug here is a topic I've found:

The workaround for this bug is

1.) sudo dnf install nss-pem-1.0.3-9.fc28 --releasever=28

2.) sudo dnf system-upgrade --releasever=28 download

This bug was already reported at https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410...

I used this workaround and it worked :-)